# Stability theory in the context of $\omega$-stable theories

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

I'm looking for some references to get me started on stability theory. More specifically, I want to find sources that talk about notions in stability theory, but for $\omega$-stable theories, which should hopefully be much easier to understand than general stable theories since things should be much nicer. (I guess even starting with strongly minimal theories is acceptable for me.) The thing I care about the most is that it should be as friendly to a beginner (having taken a first course in model theory) as possible, so loss of generality (esp. beyond $\omega$-stability) is no problem to me.

Are there such sources?

Comment: Pillay's *An Introduction to Stability Theory* is quite short and approachable

Comment: @interregno I will take a look, thanks!

Comment: To me, Marker's book comes close to what you ask.

Comment: I second the recommendation of Marker's book (*Model Theory: An Introduction*). The last three chapters (Chapters 6-8) are all about stability theory, but developed entirely in the context of $\omega$-stable theories.

Comment: What a shame, I have been using Marker but never realized there's stability in it! Judging from the ToC, it certainly looks like what I'm looking for. Thanks Primo and Alex!